# How do you go from the Subway Terminal area to the Subway Maintenance Access?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In Batman Arkham City, can you go from the Subway Terminal area to the Subway Maintenance Access? At this point I'm just running around at the end of the game and have all the gadgets. It looks like the two areas should be connected (that is, you could start in The Bowery and use the subway tunnels and come out in the Industrial District) but I can't figure out how to get from the terminal into the maintenance access area.

Is this possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops. After ten minutes of looking, found the answer as soon as I posted. Go to the very east end (past the doors you have to use open with the terminal) and then look directly up - there's a small hatch you can grapple to just past the doors.